# Using javascript to manipulate css elements, dash margin-left

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to use this

```
document.getElementById('menu2').style.marginleft = "5%";
```

To manipulate the `margin-left: 20%;` to become `margin-left: 5%;`

I don't know what to do with the dash, if it's a single word like `style.width,` it's no problem, but a dash seems problematic, what do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `marginLeft` instead, with a capital "L".

Comment: ha! I can't believe that's the solution, camel case replaces dash, anyway thank you!

Comment: Also this article was a good read, might be helpful. [Using dynamic styling information - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Using_dynamic_styling_information)

Answer (score 1):

can use this

```
$('#menu2').css({"marginLeft":"5%"});
```

[Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/phew7w78/)